# How to place svg shapes in a circle?

Tags: d3.js

I'm playing a bit with D3.js and I got most things working. But I want to place my svg shapes in a circle. So I will show the difference in data with color and text. I know how to draw circles and pie charts, but I want to basically have a circle of same size circles. And not have them overlap, the order is irrelevant. I don't know where to start, to find out the x & y for each circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another approach to this, for shapes of arbitrary size, using D3's `tree` layout: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/5CfGG/

The `tree` layout ([docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout), [example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063550)) will figure out the x,y placement of each item for you, based on a given radius and a function returning the separation between the centers of any two items. In this example, I used circles of varying sizes, so the separation between them is a function of their radii:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, radius])
    .separation(function(a, b) {
        return radiusScale(a.size) + radiusScale(b.size);
    });
```

Using the D3 `tree` layout solves the first problem, laying out the items in a circle. The second problem, as @Markus notes, is how to calculate the right radius for the circle. I've taken a slightly rough approach here, for the sake of expediency: I estimate the circumference of the circle as the sum of the diameters of the various items, with a given padding in between, then calculate radius from the circumference:

```
var roughCircumference = d3.sum(data.map(radiusScale)) * 2 +
        padding * (data.length - 1),
    radius = roughCircumference / (Math.PI * 2);
```

The circumference here isn't exact, and this will be less and less accurate the fewer items you have in the circle, but it's close enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you correctly, this is a fairly standard math question:

Simply loop over some *angle* variable in the appropriate step size and use `sin()` and `cos()` to calculate your x and y values.

For example:

Let's say you are trying to place 3 objects. There are 360 degrees in a circle. So each object is 120 degrees away from the next. If your objects are 20x20 pixels in size, place them at the following locations:

```
 x1 = sin(  0 * pi()/180) * r + xc - 10;  y1 = cos(  0 * pi()/180) * r + yc - 10
 x2 = sin(120 * pi()/180) * r + xc - 10;  y2 = cos(120 * pi()/180) * r + yc - 10
 x3 = sin(240 * pi()/180) * r + xc - 10;  y3 = cos(240 * pi()/180) * r + yc - 10
```

Here, `r` is the radius of the circle and `(xc, yc)` are the coordinates of the circle's center point. The `-10's` make sure that the objects have their center (rather than their top left corner) on the circle. The `* pi()/180` converts the degrees to radians, which is the unit most implementations of `sin()` and `cos()` require.

Note: This places the shapes equally distributed around the circle. To make sure they don't overlap, you have to pick your `r` big enough. If the objects have simple and identical boundaries, just lay out 10 of them and figure out the radius you need and then, if you need to place 20, make the radius twice as big, for 30 three times as big and so forth. If the objects are irregularly shaped and you want to place them in the optimal order around the circle to find the smallest circle possible, this problem will get extremely messy. Maybe there's a library for this, but I don't have one in the top of my head and since I haven't used D3.js, I'm not sure whether it will provide you with this functionality either.

Comment: Thanks for the background match info, I was looking for a specific D3js solution, but this helps understanding.

Comment: I am looking for a solution - which will allow the dots to be placed in other path shapes - like crescents as well as circles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340334/d3-js-user-viewer-chart

Comment: this is the answer :)

Comment: @MarkusA, great answer.  Would you also know how to find the minimal radius amount?  Or should I ask a new question entirely?  In your example 3 objects are 20x20.  By trial and error I can see that a radius of ~22.5 is *just* touching.  How can I automatically calculate this minimum radius?  My objects are irregular in size.

Comment: @Jared A circle's circumference is given by 2 * pi() * r, so if your objects where spherical, you could get a rough idea of the radius you need by taking the objects' diameters, multiplying that by the number of objects and dividing the result by 2pi(). The problem is that this only works if the objects touch on the circle's circumference. Usually, they touch inside the circle somewhere, though. While it is definitely possible to calculate the needed radius, it requires a bit more involved geometry and the formula will depend on the shape and number of objects.

Comment: @Jared It's probably easiest just to try it out. If you wanted to place 6 objects (twice as many), for example, you could use a radius of 45 (twice 22.5) and it should be roughly correct. If you would like to automate it fully, you could write a function that lays out your objects with some initial test-radius for the circle and then checks for overlaps. If it finds overlaps, it increases the radius. If not, it decreases it until it finds the smallest radius that works. If you do this in a binary-search fashion, it should be fairly quick as well.

Comment: @Jared Note that you might be able to place the objects in a smaller circle if you optimize the starting angle, also! For example for four square-shaped objects with sides of length a, the minimal radius of your "circle" is a/2 * √2, if you place them at 45°, 135°, 225° and 315°. You would end up with them being placed next to each other in a 2x2 square pattern.

Comment: @MarkusA. thanks for the help!  Dividing the sum of all the diameters by pi worked.  Your example would be (20+20+20)/PI.  [Here are some of my screenshots of this in action.](http://imgur.com/a/Och5F/)  The more objects the better.

Comment: @Jared Strange... there seems to be some factor of 2 missing... Could it be that 20 is the **radius** of the spheres in the screenshots you posted rather than the diameter? And, yes, the more spheres you have the better since the point where they touch will end up closer and closer on top of the circle (as compared to the radius of the circle).