# d3.js User viewer chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Developing a chart which will provide a user a visual for who has viewed them. The inner circle shows matches (user following/being followed), the next ring - user following others, the last ring - the followers of the user.

[image]

I've mocked the cy, cx positions, but what would it take to position them like this - to bound the orange circles into the various circle quadrants?

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/281/

```
sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "orange")
        .attr("r", 6)
        .attr("cx", function(d, i){return 2 + (i*80)})
        .attr("cy", function(d, i){return (i*80)});
```

Comment: I've seen this example, but not sure if it applys. http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/5CfGG/ - its almost like I need to place the small circles inside cresent shapes

Comment: I've merged the two examples together. How would I be able to control the quadrant area for these dots. http://jsfiddle.net/5CfGG/26/ - is it possible for it to follow any shaped area - not just a circle?

Comment: I've got the dots to spiral - but I am not convinced this is the best way of placing the dots into a custom shape path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"LATEST CODE" - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/336/ (Note: Merely conceptual, highly **non**-optimized!)*

I'm not sure if d3 can do this automatically somehow, but you can always just figure out the ***x*** and ***y*** positions of your dots yourself with some math:

One way to do it is to just place each dot randomly until it sits correctly. This is definitely not the fastest approach, but if you don't have too many dots to place, it might still be way good enough.

Let's say your smallest circle has radius ***r<sub>s</sub>*** and center point (***x<sub>s</sub>***, ***y<sub>s</sub>***) and your middle circle ***r<sub>m</sub>*** and (***x<sub>m</sub>***, ***y<sub>m</sub>***) and your largest circle ***r<sub>l</sub>*** and (***x<sub>l</sub>***, ***y<sub>l</sub>***), then you can check which circle a dot does or does not fall into by comparing its distance from the center-point of the circle to the radius of that circle:

For example, if you want to place a dot into the middle circle:

- Pick a random position (***x***, ***y***) so that it can fall anywhere in that circle:

  - ***x<sub>m</sub>*** - ***r<sub>m</sub>*** ≤ ***x*** ≤ ***x<sub>m</sub>*** + ***r<sub>m</sub>***
  - ***y<sub>m</sub>*** - ***r<sub>m</sub>*** ≤ ***y*** ≤ ***y<sub>m</sub>*** + ***r<sub>m</sub>***
- Make sure it actually is inside the circle:

  - Check (***x*** - ***x<sub>m</sub>***)<sup>2</sup> + (***y*** - ***y<sub>m</sub>***)<sup>2</sup> ≤ ***r<sub>m</sub>***<sup>2</sup>
  - If this is not the case, start over and pick a different (***x***, ***y***)
- Make sure it is **not** inside the smaller circle:

  - Check (***x*** - ***x<sub>s</sub>***)<sup>2</sup> + (***y*** - ***y<sub>s</sub>***)<sup>2</sup> > ***r<sub>s</sub>***<sup>2</sup>
  - If this is not the case, start over and pick a different (***x***, ***y***)

Now you have some random point that is inside the middle circle, but not the small one. Placing one into the larger circle works the same way (just replace ***x<sub>m</sub>***, ***y<sub>m</sub>***, and ***r<sub>m</sub>*** with ***x<sub>l</sub>***, ***y<sub>l</sub>***, and ***r<sub>l</sub>*** as well as ***x<sub>s</sub>***, ***y<sub>s</sub>***, and ***r<sub>s</sub>*** with ***x<sub>m</sub>***, ***y<sub>m</sub>***, and ***r<sub>m</sub>***). To place a dot into the smallest circle, you only need to check the first condition (with ***x<sub>m</sub>***, ***y<sub>m</sub>***, and ***r<sub>m</sub>*** replaced by ***x<sub>s</sub>***, ***y<sub>s</sub>***, and ***r<sub>s</sub>***).

Now, you can either stop here (but depending on your dot-density, this might not be the prettiest picture) or, you can try to space the dots a little nicer relative to each other. One way to do this is the following:

- Loop over all dots (***x<sub>1</sub>***, ***y<sub>1</sub>***) ... (***x<sub>n</sub>***, ***y<sub>n</sub>***)
- Calculate the distance from each dot to each other dot
- Find the two that are closest together
- Of those two, figure out which one is closer to its neighbors
- Remove this dot and place it again randomly using the method described above
- Either repeat this some number of times or until you get a minimum distance between any two dots that is acceptable (I would just try out what works best)

By adjusting the two check-equations above, you can also add a little bit of clearance around the borders of your circles that the dots will avoid, by replacing ***r<sub>m</sub>***<sup>2</sup> with (***r<sub>m</sub>*** - ***d***)<sup>2</sup> and ***r<sub>s</sub>***<sup>2</sup> with (***r<sub>s</sub>*** + ***d***)<sup>2</sup>.

There are definitely a bunch of ways to optimize this simple approach: For example you can pick your initial (***x***, ***y***) position in polar coordinates by choosing ***r*** and ***α*** instead and then calculating ***x*** and ***y*** from them to make sure that you never pick a dot that is not inside the circle you want. Just make sure you pick ***r*** from a correctly weighted distribution so that ***x*** and ***y*** turn out to be uniformly distributed. Also, you can check the distance from a newly placed dot to all its neighbors immediately when placing the dot rather than in a second step at the end. For example, find 10 places for each dot and then always pick the one out of those with the largest distance to its closest neighbor.

**UPDATE**

And this is what it looks like without worrying about dot spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/328/

The relevant section implementing the dot placement is here (variable names changed to match above):

```
function getXCoordinateInCircleSection(i, xm, ym, rm, xs, ys, rs) {
    done = false;
    while (!done) {
        x = getRandomCoordinate(xm-rm, xm+rm);
        y = getRandomCoordinate(ym-rm, ym+rm);
        done = true;
        if ((x-xm)*(x-xm)+(y-ym)*(y-ym) >  (rm-10)*(rm-10)) done = false;
        if ((x-xs)*(x-xs)+(y-ys)*(y-ys) <= (rs+10)*(rs+10)) done = false;
    }
    window.ys[i] = y;
    return x;
}

function getYCoordinateInCircleSection(i) {
    return window.ys[i];
}
```

And with improved dot spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/329/

(Both of these are based on http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/326/ created by @TheOldCounty)

Comment: I see - so we start by placing the container circles on top of each other. Then assign smaller dots to each of the container circles - place the dots randomly - and if it detects that its obscured by the container circle on top of it, move again - until it finds a place when its not obscured. Is there a basic demo to this maths? with say 2 squares and 2 dots?

Comment: It sounds familiar to this issue - with trying to spread the pie labels - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939977/d3-js-spreading-labels-for-pie-charts

Comment: @TheOldCounty Sounds correct, yep. I don't know of any demo of this, but it's probably not too hard to implement. ;) BTW: If you add the clearance around the borders of the circles (as I just added), you only need to check the distance between dots in the same circle if you want to space them more evenly.

Comment: @TheOldCounty Yep, spacing the dots inside the circle is pretty much exactly the same problem as spacing the labels on a chart. You're just also adding the constraints that the dots need to remain in their respective circle-section.

Comment: Ok. so the first step is plot the dots randomly in each container. Then to loop through the dots. But how do you detect if the dot is obscured?

Comment: @TheOldCounty By calculating its distance from the center of the other circle and comparing that to the radius. The only thing you have to make sure is that you specify the dot's coordinates and the coordinates of the center of the other circle in the same coordinate system. Let's say you are working inside the coordinates of the "div" of the big circle where x goes from 0 to 2*rl-1 and y goes from 0 to 2*rl-1 and you want to make the picture look like above (the middle circle is 2/3 the size of the big one), then the center of your middle circle is at (xm=2/3*rl, ym=rl) with radius rm=2/3*rl.

Comment: Well I've cleaned up the initial demo - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/323/ - I am still not sure on how the maths is to be applied

Comment: Here is an example with the 3 quadrants created - and dots applied to each. http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/326/  - currently the coordinates are randomized - and you can specify the max radius per quadrant - but I am not sure how to expand the example to start to re-position the dots - and do the following checks you mentioned Markus

Comment: @TheOldCounty Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/328/ Note, that this code does not yet make sure that the dots are equally spaced.

Comment: Great stuff Markus, ok so how does this work - getXCoordinateInCircleSection, getYCoordinateInCircleSection

Comment: @TheOldCounty And here's the same thing with fixed up dot spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/329/

Comment: @TheOldCounty It works exactly as described in my answer, except for working around the way that d3 calls the functions: The getXCoordinateInCircleSection actually calculates both, the x and the y coordinate of a new dot: it keeps picking a random xp and yp until it finds one that is in the circle of radius r around (x, y) but <b>not</b> in the circle of radius ra (a for "avoid") around (xa, ya). Then it returns the xp coordinate and stores the yp coordinate in an array (windows.yps) so that it can later return that when you call getYCoordinateInCircleSection

Comment: @TheOldCounty The reason you need to use windows.yps is that d3 first asks for all the x coordinates only (calls getXCoordinateInCircleSection a bunch of times, with increasing i) and then asks for all the y coordinates (calls getXCoordinateInCircleSection a bunch of times, with the same i).

Comment: @TheOldCounty The second version then simply places each dot a bunch of times and looks for the one with the largest distance to all other already placed dots. Note that the way it's written it still does not guarantee that dots are never on top of each other!

Comment: @TheOldCounty Get's a bit slow with this many points... I replaced the i*i+1 with just i+1 (tries less placements for each point and seems to be good enough) and messed with the circle edge clearance (20 -> 12) to get this: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/335/

Comment: @TheOldCounty BTW: There are a LOT of things you can still do to make this code run quite a bit faster if you need to display more points or (heaven forbid) support Internet Explorer ;). For example: Don't evaluate the second if statement if "done" is already false. Stop calculating distances if "dist" is already smaller than "best". Stop trying more points if "best" is already more than (pick a number) 20. Just to name a few... :)

Comment: Markus - I put your first fine tune into practice - "don't evaluate second statement if done is already false". Not sure how to implement the other suggestions - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/358/

Comment: @TheOldCounty Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/377/ I also added calculating r^2 only once and cleaned up a couple of other things. On my machine in Chrome it now places 3x500 dots in about a second. If you need more speed, you can tune the maximum number of tries (maxcount) or you can look for even more ways to optimize the code (e.g. pick xp, yp more cleverly). You could also determine maxcount dynamically based on how many dots you need to place (fewer dots -> higher maxcount). But now I have to go focus on my work here... Good luck! :)

Comment: I added a force element to the code - but its not taking any effect, thought it would be nice to see the dots repel each other for a bit -     var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(1000)
        .gravity(100)
        .size([width, height]);    - but instead they are just moving position here and there during start up

Comment: What about the ability to add collision detection instead? - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231307

Comment: - I got a similar problem -- this time merging a dougnut pie chart and bubbles -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176404/d3-js-clustering-bubbles-to-segments